# Sum of Differences in an Array Codewars (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm learning to code and I'm on the for loops section now. I encountered an interesting question on Codewars and decided to tackle it. Here it is:

> Your task is to sum the differences between consecutive pairs in the array in descending order.
>
> For example:
>
> sumOfDifferences([2, 1, 10])
> Returns 9
>
> Descending order: [10, 2, 1]
>
> Sum: (10 - 2) + (2 - 1) = 8 + 1 = 9
>
> If the array is empty or the array has only one element the result should be 0 (Nothing in Haskell).>

Since I more or less only know for loops, here is my answer. It passed all the tests, but I had to separate the loops. **My question is this: is there a way to solve this problem using nested loops?** I initially thought I could, but I kept getting NaN as an output.

```
   function differenceAddition(array) {
      if (array.length == 1) {
        return 0;
      } else if (array == []) {
        return [];
      } else
        for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
          for (let j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (array[j] < array[j + 1]) {
              let temp = array[j];
              array[j] = array[j + 1];
              array[j + 1] = temp;
            }
          }
        }
      let newArray = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
        newArray[i] = array[i] - array[i + 1];
      }
      let sum = 0;
      for (let i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
        sum += newArray[i];
      }
      // newArray.pop();
      return sum;
      // return array;
    }
```

Comment: `else if (array == [])` can never be true - but that's not your problem - use array reduce

Comment: oh, and you'd never need nested loops for the solution - unless I don't understand the question

Comment: single line function ...`const fn = array => array.slice(1).reduce((a, b, i) => a + Math.abs(b - array[i]), 0)`

Answer (score 2):

First of all -- unless there's something more to this challenge, don't write loops yourself to sort an array. Use the built-in sorting function for it.

```js
let arr = [2, 1, 10];
arr.sort((a,b) => b - a);
console.log(arr);
```

Great, now we're in descending order. Now, all we need is one `for` loop to calculate our sum.

```js
let arr = [2, 1, 10];

arr.sort((a,b) => b - a);

let sum = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; ++i) {
    sum += arr[i] - arr[i + 1];
}

console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use nested loops when you can get the result using a single loop. In JS you can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to achieve the result.

```js
function sumOfDifferences(arr) {
  return arr
    .sort((a, b) => b - a)
    .reduce((acc, curr, index, array) => {
      const next = array[index + 1];
      if (!isNaN(curr - next)) {
        acc += curr - next;
      }
      return acc;
    }, 0);
}

console.log(sumOfDifferences([]));
console.log(sumOfDifferences([10]));
console.log(sumOfDifferences([10, 1, 2]));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
let numberList = [2, 1, 10];
// sorting for descending order
numberList.sort((a,b) => b - a);

let sum = 0;
let dif = 0

for(let i=0; i<numberList.length-1; i++){
    dif = numberList[i] - numberList[i+1];
    sum += dif
};

console.log("Result=> ",sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function sumOfDifferences(arr) {
  arr.sort((a,b) => b - a);
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; ++i) {
      sum += arr[i] - arr[i + 1];
  }
  return sum;
}

console.log(sumOfDifferences([2, 1, 10]));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
function sumOfDifferences(arr){
 return arr.length > 1 ? Math.max(...arr) - Math.min(...arr) : 0
}
```

Comment: It just happens to return the correct answer for the one test case given. If you add any nonzero values to the array, you will see that this does not work.